# JQuery change border color for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, duration

How can I change border color of the clicked  for 10 seconds and then change back to original?

Comment: Bind click event on button. In handler change border color. `setTimeout` with 10 seconds to reset the border color.

Comment: Please put in your html

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: Asking a question on StackOverflow should be the last action you take when trying to find an answer to a problem. You're expected to try and solve the problem yourself first, either by looking at other questions online first or asking coworkers/friends.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try this solution ? :)

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
    elem = $(this);
    elem.css('border-color', 'blue');
    setTimeout(function(){
        elem.css('border-color', 'red'); },
        10000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `setTimeout` for that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;

  $('div').click(function() {
    // cancel previous timeout
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var self = $(this);
    
    // set new border collor. Or add new class for CSS integration
    self.css('border-color', 'green');

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      // reset CSS
      self.css('border-color', '');
    }, 5000); // time in miliseconds, so 5s = 5000ms
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery do something like this:

```js
$(".test").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({"border-color":"#fff"}).delay(1000).animate({"border-color":"#c00"});
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  border: 5px solid #c00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

Please note that you can't do it with jQuery alone - because animate can't use colors. So you need to add jQuery UI for Example to extend jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to try like this

```
  $('#btn').click(function () {
        $(this).css('border-color', '#fff');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#btn').css('border-color', '#000');
        },10000);
    });
```

Comment: Your `$(this)` inside `setTimeout` will not show to `div` but to function itself.